# extracting multiple values from xml using R

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I am having a hard time extracting values from an XML file. I would like to take the average of each "length" (value between the `<length>` tags) for each hour of the day. In this XML file, all of the data comes from the same day: 2013-11-28

An example is shown below:

```
 <root>
        <item>
            <time>2013-11-28T00:00:00-05:00</time>
            <day>2013-11-28</day>
            <length>150</length>
        </item>
        <item>
            <time>2010-11-28T00:15:00-05:00</time>
            <day>2010-11-28</day>
            <length>200</length>
        </item>
        <item>
            <time>2010-11-28T00:30:00-05:00</time>
            <day>2010-11-28</day>
            <length>127.83</length>
        </item>
</root>
```

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
   hour         average_length
12:00-12:59     some_average
1:00-1:59       some_average
2:00-2:59       some_average
```

Thank you!

Comment: This question should be separated in two separate questions: 
1. How to read and format xml
2. how to calculate hourly average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to read and format xml

Using the `xml2` package and assuming `text` as in your example, we use

```
 xml_obj <- read_xml(text)
```

to create a xml object.
We can navigate in this objects using the various functions in the library that you can read about [here](https://github.com/hadley/xml2). In this particular case we want to find all the elements of types `time` and `length` and then bind them in a `data.frame`.

```
# Find all elements of type time
times <- xml_find_all(xml_obj, '//time') %>% xml_text()
# Find all elements of type length
lengths <- xml_find_all(xml_obj, '//length') %>% xml_text()

# Merge the two to create the final data.frame
final <- data.frame(time = times, length = lengths)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. When I tried to create an Xml object using `xml_read`, I got this error: `Error: could not find function "xml_read"` However, I have the xml2 package installed.

Comment: Thanks! Also, when I tried to run `times <- date = xml_find_all(xml_obj, '//time') %>% xml_text()` I got an error saying ` object 'times' not found` so I added parenthesis like so: `times <- (date = xml_find_all(xml_obj, '//time') %>% xml_text())` and i think that did the trick. However, when i tried to run `final <- data.frame(time = times, length = lengths)` I got this error: `arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 92`. I believe there is an error with parsing the time?

Comment: I edited the question, something went wrong copy-pasting, check it now

Comment: I really appreciate your help. However, I'm getting the same error: `arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 92`. When I checked into the `times` variable, there is nothing in it, which I think is the problem. All of the values inside `lengths` seem to be correct.

Comment: `xml_find_all(xml_obj, '//time') ` what's the result? The answer works for me on the XML  you pasted.. something changed in the original XML text?

Comment: my bad, it works! thank you. I still need to figure out how to calculate hourly average but, you are correct, that should be a separate question.